Flink Kubernetes Operator pods resources request and limits
I have not been able to find a way to limit the resource requests and limits for pods while using Flink Kubernetes Operator v1.8.
I also tried configuring it in the containers section of the podTemplate, but it did not take effect.
I would like to know if Flink Kubernetes Operator v1.8 supports controlling pod resources.

Looking forward to having the issue resolved.

CPU Limits
You can accomplish this through the use of a limit-factor configuration as it relates to CPU as follows:
spec:
  ...
  flinkConfiguration:
  ...
    kubernetes.taskmanager.cpu.limit-factor: "x"
    kubernetes.jobmanager.cpu.limit-factor: "y"

This in conjunction with the values that you define under both of your job/task manager sections to calculate what your limits would be:
jobManager:
  resource:
    memory: "..."
    cpu: ...
taskManager:
  resource:
    memory: ...
    cpu: ...

You can think of this as the minimum possible values used by the pods (e.g. taskManager.resource.cpu would be the minimum) and it would be scaled up to a factor defined by your limit-factor above:
# taskmanager example
request: taskManager.resource.cpu
limit: taskManager.resource.cpu * kubernetes.taskmanager.cpu.limit-factor

# jobmanager example
request: jobManager.resource.cpu
limit: jobManager.resource.cpu * kubernetes.jobmanager.cpu.limit-factor

Memory Limits
If you are using a version of Flink and/or the Flink Operator that supports it, you might consider using Autotuning which works in conjunction with the autoscaling support in Flink to allow you to define the limits for given resources and allows Flink to assign resources up to that definition as need.
